# Routine to Upload Files to Website

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a certain situation which I'm out of ideas on how exactly to proceed. I have a very repetitive task to do which consists of:

- Choose file from list of files
- Press submit
- Repeat until all files in folder have been submitted/uploaded

Sometimes I have 100's of files at a time, which can be very time consuming. I would like to write a script to automate this routine.

This is the visual of the page in question:

[Menu Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6C6o.png)

Of course this is represented by the following html code:

```html
<input type="file" class="inputFile" data-name="userNumListFile">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" method="post" action="/give/giveItemBatch" enctype="multipart/form-data"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></form>
```

Those are the two entries that represent what I need to send a HTTP request to. I have done something similar in Python where I used the following code to access a authorization only webpage and then use bs4 to gather info needed.

```
import requests
payload = {'username': 'user',
        'password': 'pw',
        'rememberMe': 'true'}
with requests.Session() as s:
url = "http://yada.com"
p = s.post(url, data=payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(p.text, "html.parser")
```

I was wondering if there is something similar to the above where I can submit a file to be uploaded and then press the submit button.

I would then cycle through all the files on my folder, that's the easy part.

Comment: Why do you need bs4? Does the form have dynamic fields? If not, just use `files` for your file and `data` for the rest inputs.

Comment: BS4 was just a code example, I do not need it for this case. Can you elaborate on the the use of 'files' and 'data' for the inputs? not sure how to do it.

Comment: `s.post(url, data=payload, files=my_files)`,  [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use requests.post inside a loop, the name of the remote folder. First read  local files and store it inside one array then start a Loop and put inside requests.post with the remote target.